# Accidental git stash, now can't pop - how to undo?

Tags: git

So, I checked out a branch, did some work, stashed the changes, and checked out master:

```
   $ git checkout my-branch
   ... make changes
   $ git stash
   $ git checkout master
```

Then, I accidentally applied my stash to master, where it shouldn't go, and got lots of conflict messages:

```
   $ git stash apply
   Auto-merging app/common/collections/visitors-realtime.js
   CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/common/collections/visitors-realtime.js
   ...
```

Oops! Now I want to undo this. Trying to pop the stash doesn't work:

```
   $ git stash pop
   app/support/backdrop_stub/responses/licensing_realtime.json: needs merge
   styles/common/visitors_realtime.scss: needs merge
   unable to refresh index ...
```

And I can't just check out the other branch:

```
$ git checkout my-branch
app/support/backdrop_stub/responses/licensing_realtime.json: needs merge
styles/common/visitors_realtime.scss: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

I want to un-apply these changes to master, go back to my branch, and apply them there. How can I do this?

Comment: Just reset back to the commit before you applied the stash? git reset --hard <SHA>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have applied your stash you should have the changed still in your stash, `git stash list`

In that case you can do `git reset --hard` and go to your branch and do `git stash apply` or `git stash pop`

The difference between `pop` and `apply` is that with `apply` the changes will remain in your stash, whereas with `pop` it will be removed from your stash list

Answer (score 1):

You have to clean your working copy first - aka reset to the last commited state:

```
git reset --hard
```

Then checkout the latest commit, and re-apply the stash